# How do i have a statement executed if .then fails

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
   firestore.collection("Something").where("User2", "==", "")
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {    
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            const docRef = firestore.collection("Something").doc(doc.id); 
            docRef.update({

                User2: messageseqno,
        })
    })
    .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
        const docRef = firestore.collection("Something").doc(); 
          var nullvalue = "";

          docRef.update({

              User1: messageseqno,
              User2: nullvalue,

          })
    });
    })
```

I need this to execute like if-else statements. considering .then is if , what can i do to get else.

The above code shows me an error

> "Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined"

Comment: `.catch` if I know my Promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I put .catch inside the then-function. It should come direct after, sorry for the typo.

Use .catch after .then. The catch method gives us an error object.

```
firestore.collection("Something").where("User", "==", input)
.get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {    
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        const docRef = firestore.collection("Something").doc(doc.id); 
        docRef.update({

            //set of statements if .then is true

        })
    })
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
  // Do stuff when query fails
 });
```

Comment: Are your sure your functions returns a promise? Is the function in .then running?

Comment: If the function doesn't run , i want .catch to work. Is it possible?

Comment: It's maybe just a typo by me, I will update the answer

Comment: What happens when .where is not true , will .catch work?

Comment: I think you will have to check inside your .then if you have a document. Like if(!doc) {
  // Do stuff if you don't find a document
}

The .catch will only fire if the query to the database fails

Comment: Did it work for you? If so, please accept my answer to help others :) Cheers!

Comment: I do not have the document,yet .catch wont fire

Comment: .catch will not fire unless the connection to the DB fails. If you want to handle if you have found a document or not, you will have to do that with a simple if-statement in the .then()

Answer (score 0):

You can also use async and await syntax for this, in a try-catch block

```js
async function getRecords() {

try {
const records = await firestore.collection("Something").where("User2", "==", "")
    .get();
    
    
    
    //do stuff with records as an array
    
    
    records.forEach(function(doc) {
        const docRef = firestore.collection("Something").doc(doc.id); 
        docRef.update({

            //set of statements if .then is true

        })
        }
}
catch(e) {
console.log("Error",e.message);
//handle your exceptions here
}

}
```